# Meteor / Node.js parsing large number of files gets very slow

Tags: node.js, csv, meteor

I have about 1000 CSV files that need parsing. Each one contains about 1000 rows, for 1 million total records. The data need to be transformed and then saved to the db, which is why I have to do this through my app.

My problem is that the parser gradually slows down as it loops through the files, to the point where it will take forever to complete the run.

Here's how it's currently set up.

```
var files = [ file1Path, file2Path.... file1000Path ];

function parseFile(index) {
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  var filePath = files[index];
  var stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

  //parse using fast-csv npm module
  csv.fromStream(stream, { config })
     .on('data', function (row) {
        transformAndSave(row);
     })
     .on('end', function () {
       console.log( new Date().getTime() - startTime + " elapsed " );
       parseFile(index + 1)
     });
}
parseFile(0);
```

I've tried this a few different ways and it's basically the same thing every time. The first file completes in 2 seconds, by the 8th file we're at 5 or 6 seconds, later on it climbs to 24 seconds, etc. Other things I've tried include doing... `files.forEach(function (file) { //run the parser })`, doing batches of 100 at a time or even 5 at a time, and it makes no difference: it progressively slows down from a rate of 500 per second to 1 or 2 per second.

Does anybody have ideas for how I can prevent this slow down? Part of the reason could be that `stream.on('end')` completes before `transformAndSave` is finished, potentially creating a backlog. But at this point I'm out of ideas and would appreciate any help anyone could offer.

Thanks for much in advance!!

Daniel

---

note for Meteor people. I'm calling this function as a Meteor method. Not sure if that makes any difference, but in case it does, now you know.

---

**Update**
Here's is the log output demonstrating the steady rise in memory usage and processing time.

[image: Log output]

Comment: In the end I think this is a meteor-specific memory leak, so I'm marking @Mike P as giving the correct answer. Thanks, Mike!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a resource problem, as in you're running out of memory. I would try an approach that doesn't use a recursive function which might allow resources to be released more readily. One approach could be to use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

```
var Logger = require('arsenic-logger');
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');
var csv = require('fast-csv');
var path = require('path');

Logger.echoMemoryUsage();

var testDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'test');

fs.readdir(testDir, (err, files) => {

    Logger.debug(files);

    if (err) {
        Logger.error(err);
    }

    async.mapLimit(files, 2, function(file, cb) {

        var startTime = new Date().getTime();
        var stream = fs.createReadStream(testDir+'/'+file);

        Logger.debug("Reading: " + file);

        config = {};

        //parse using fast-csv npm module
        csv.fromStream(stream, config)
            .on('data', function(row) {
                //Logger.debug(row);
                //transformAndSave(row);
            })
            .on('error', function(err) {
                Logger.error(err);
                cb(err);
            })
            .on('end', function() {
                Logger.debug(new Date().getTime() - startTime + " elapsed ");
                setTimeout(cb, 1000);
            });

    }, function(err, results) {
        Logger.info("Finished!");
        process.exit(1);
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your super quick response. This approach makes sense, but it's still reading all the files into the stream all at once. `.on('end')` isn't being called for each file. Am I missing something? Thanks again. Daniel

Comment: It should read each file into a separate stream, and shut it down. Its probably best to use async.mapLimit too so it does them in batches. I'll experiment and see....

Comment: So I tested, and it does seem to close the stream each time. I've updated my answer with more complete code. I used the arsenic-logger (my project) as the Logger spits out memory usage so you can see memory being released over time.

Comment: The logger is extremely helpful, but unfortunately it hasn't resolved the leak in my case. I've updated the original post with a screen cap of the log output, showing the steady rise in memory usage and the time it takes to process 2 files. Nearly there!

Comment: I'll try with some larger files. One idea might be (if you're using async), to call the callback after transfromAndSave is finished rather than when the stream has been read?